using eventContent option causes rerendering of my event content. It's not happening for the view without eventContent being set
I'm using fullcalendar react and want to customize the way events are displayed on the weekly calendar view. Even if my eventContent is just a basic one like returning the title, it causes a re-render of the events everytime I navigate to prev/next week. If I don't use the eventContent option, it renders only once. I'm using thousands of events(earnings dates and info of companies in stock market) on the calendar. Is there anyway to find out how to not trigger the re-render?
The events are given to the FullCalendar as a callback function. The function takes the start and end dates of the current view using fetchEvents info and the data is returned from reading a json file using success callback.
const eventContent = (eventInfo) => {
    const {event} = eventInfo;
    return (<span>{event.title}</span>)
}

<FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
          initialView="dayGridWeek"
          weekends={true}
          events={events}
          eventDisplay="block"
          eventOrder="start, title"
          timeZone="local"
          eventContent={eventContent}
          headerToolbar={{
            start: "prev",
            center: "title",
            end: "next",
          }}
          allDaySlot={false}
        />
      )}
    </>

I tried to set my custom view for events, like having the company name(set in extendedProps of event), start time, ticker symbol of the company(set as event title) and expecting to render once.

when you say re render what do you mean?  obviously the calendar has to re render if the week changes as it is displaying totally different events,  are you saying that the events are fetched again?  did you try memoizing the fetching of the events and the eventcontent function?

I mean, when I click on prev or next week, if not eventContent option is provided, it takes 1-2 seconds to switch the view and I could see all the 3000+ events in that week loaded. When I use the eventContent option, it takes the same 1-2 seconds to switch, and I can see all the events in customized view already being there, but after that it removes all the events and loads them again. I could see that happening everytime and I checked the network tab for additional requests. It makes only one call to get the events, but somehow it re-renders all the events when using the eventContent option

@BryanDellinger this could be about how FullCalendar tries to render the events internally by default. to give more clarity, the during the events rerendering using eventContent, I could even see "empty events" like no data, but blocks associated with them. Let's say monday has 50 events and tuesday has 250 events, I could see empty blocks with borders maybe, a stack of 50 and 250 on both days even before the content is filled with event data. it's taking water out of a bottle and refilling again
